# How to best implement silent email mail merge via asp.net

Tags: c#, email, mailmerge, mailing-list

I've come across many threads describing how to send a single email to multiple recipients (bulk email).

I also read about mail-merge using, for example, outlook. Finally, I searched for sending emails silently.

With all these procedures, I am a bit confused as to what the suggested approach is to send individualized emails to a list of people from my .Net application.

My concerns are:
- is there a way around sending individual emails?

- is there a risk to get blocked by the SMTP provider, in case of hundreds of emails and, if so, is there a workaround?
- is there a way to send individual mails silently through email clients such as outlook to have the email as sent email, but without having to click "send" for each and every email?

EDIT: to reflect [Claies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2495283/claies) comment, let refine a bit:

Suppose I know how to generate a personal email for individuals and I have, in my .Net application, a list of `<email_address, email_content>`.

-What is the suggested approach to send these emails? 
-If via the installed mail client, is there a way to perform it sliently?

I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad and also seems to have mixed terminology.  You ask about bulk mailing, mail merging, and client scripting all at once.  Try to narrow your focus a bit.

Comment: Blind Email only has one To Address.  Most mail server support Blind Email.  Some server limit the number of To (Blind or not Blind) Addresses on an email so you have to check your server for these restrictions.  Also some mail limit the number of items in the Out Box.  Server don't instantly send emails.  The emails are queued and sit in the  Out Box until the server sends the email.  So you may have to wait between emails to make sure you don't exceed the max Out Box size.

Comment: Your question still seems broad, so I'll try to help you a bit more in getting it focused.  When you send an e-mail from a server, the server is a client.  The client can put any `smtp from:` header on the e-mail, but the only two parties who know what is in the header are the client (your server) and the recipient.  The user's client, and thus their sent items, would not have a record of the transmission.

Comment: if, however, you were trying to automate sending as the user, your server program would need some way to log on as your user into their mail system, or the app would need to be run on the individual user's PC to automate their client.  You haven't really given enough information about your program to identify which scenario you are trying (direct send, server side user delegation, client app).

Comment: each of the above mentioned scenarios has positive and negative aspects that can either address or cause the concerns that you have outlined in the question body.  Hopefully you can see why the question focus needs to be narrowed.

Comment: Claies - "installed mail client" is meant as what you call "mail app". I should have said "outlook" to make it clear, although other mail apps should apply (thunderbird, windows mail, ...). Anyway, the question is precisely about what method to chose: send individual emails to outlook or make users enter SMTP credentials so the app sends mails directly? I won't use the first approach, as my App won't have access to its own smpt server. I hope it is clearer now...?!

Comment: you don't "send emails to outlook"; you *could* "automate" outlook, assuming you are targeting outlook specifically, though it sounds as though you aren't.  And you still haven't expressly said if this is an app installed for each user on their pc or an app installed on a server operating for multiple users.

Comment: also, an smtp server isn't a requirement for sending mail, only receiving...

Comment: The app is on each individual's computer, which makes a lot of the above confusion clearer - I should have started there. So as I said, sending "VIA" outlook, not "TO" outlook, so users can store the sent items in there. The simple "mailto" command is an option, but only if it is possible to have it either "silent" or as a single-click for all messages - opening 300 new email windows is simply not an option.

Comment: Right, so now the question is becoming a bit clearer; unfortunately there isn't really a one size fits all answer here.  I have a few more thoughts on the matter, I will respond again when I am at a pc